# Hoffman and Kunze Linear Algebra Exercise on projections

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Here is the question.

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ which commutes with every projection operator on $V$. What can you say about $T$?

I want to deduce that every subspace of $V$ is $T$-invariant. I already showed that the kernel and range of every projection on $V$ is $T$-invariant, but I could not go further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try to show the following.

- If $T$ is not diagonalizable, then there must be a subspace that fails to be $T$-invariant.
- If $T$ has two distinct eigenvalues, then there must be a subspace that fails to be $T$-invariant.

If $T$ is diagonalizable and has exactly one eigenvalue, then what can you say about $T$?

Comment: **(1)** Since $T$ is not diagonalizable, $\exists 0\neq \alpha \in V$ such $\alpha$ is not eigenvector of $T$, i.e. $T(\alpha)\neq c\alpha$, $\forall c\in F$. So $T(\alpha)\notin \text{span}(\alpha)$. Thus $\text{span}(\alpha)$ is not $T$-invariant. **(2)** Suppose $T(\alpha)=c_1\alpha$ and $T(\beta)=c_2\beta$, where $c_1\neq c_2$. It’s easy to check $\{\alpha ,\beta\}$ is independent. So $T(\alpha +\beta)\notin \text{span}(\alpha +\beta)$. Thus $\text{span}(\alpha +\beta)$ is not $T$-invariant.

Comment: **(3)** Suppose $\dim (V)\lt \infty$ and $T$ is diagonalizable. Then $\exists B$ basis of $V$ such that $\forall \alpha \in B$, $\alpha$ is eigenvector of $T$. Since $T$ has exactly one eigenvalue (let say $c\in F$), we have $T(\alpha)=c\alpha$, $\forall \alpha \in B$. Thus $T=cI$. How these hints prove every subspace of $V$ is invariant under $T$?

Comment: @user264745 These hints do not prove that. The asker said that they showed “the projection and range of every projection on $V$ is $T$-invariant”, which is enough to deduce that every subspace of $V$ is invariant under $T$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have shown that all images of projections in $V$ are $T$-invariant, then you have shown that all subspaces are $T$-invariant. Just using the weaker fact that all $1$-dimensional subspaces are $T$-invariant, all nonzero vectors are eigenvectors (since the span of a nonzero vector is $T$-invariant if and only if it is an eigenvector). That means there is but one eigenspace, and it is all of $V$. Conclude.

Comment: How do we get that all 1-dimensional subspaces are $T$-invariant?

Comment: @Serhan Well they are the images (ranges) of the projections onto them. I assumed you already showed that such images are $T$-invariant, since the question says that.

Comment: Actually, this is precisely the point where I get confused, I want to argue on something based on the projections onto some subspaces of $V$. But the question does not specify whether $V$ is finite-dimensional or not. If it is finite-dimensional, then I can construct some one-dimensional subspaces, each of which spanned by one basis element. Then projections onto these subspaces make sense. However, what if $V$ is not finite-dimensional?

Comment: @Serhan Even though I did not think about infinite dimensional space when I wrote the answer, nothing I said is actually assuming finite dimension. One-dimensional subspaces still have projectors, so are $T$-invariant, and they then contain only eigenvectors (with the exception of the zero vector). There can be only one eigenspace, and it must fill the whole (finite or infinite dimensional) space.

Comment: How can we define the projections on one-dimensional subspaces when $V$ is infinite-dimensional? I defined projections on vector spaces which can be decomposed into finitely many direct summands. I am not comfortable with directly stating that "Let $E$ be a projection on one-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$." I want to specifically define it and the only way I know for this definition is through finitely many direct summands.

Comment: @Serhan If $S$ and $T$ are complementary subspaces, every vector $v$ can be uniquely written $v=s+t$ with $s\in S$ and $t\in T$,, and then $v\mapsto s$ is the projection onto $S$ parallel to $T$. This works in particular for $S$ of dimension$~1$, any of whose complements $T$ will have codimension$~1$. And (if you admit that all vector spaces have bases, which amounts to accepting the axiom of choice) every subspace has complementary subspaces, so such projections exist for every subspace, including $1$-dimensional ones. One cannot be much more explicit for general vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\dim (V)\lt \infty$. Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. Then $\exists W’$ subspace of $V$ such that $V=W\oplus W’$. By [theorem 10 section 6.7](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625534/861687), $W$ is invariant under $T$$\iff$$TE_1=E_1T$. Since $T$ commutes with every projection on $V$, we have $W$ is invariant under $T$. Thus every subspace of $V$ is invariant under $T$.